# Numpy requirement not satisified for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on jupyter-notebook.

When i give the command

```
import pandas
    df = pandas.read_csv('/home/pglab1/WiFi Strength_Mar06.csv')
    print(df)
```

it shows the following error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b8728196942c> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas
      2 df = pandas.read_csv('/home/pglab1/WiFi Strength_Mar06.csv')
      3 print(df)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 # numpy compat
---> 23 from pandas.compat.numpy import *
     24 
     25 try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
     20                       'your numpy version is {0}.\n'
     21                       'Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.12.0 to use '
---> 22                       'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
     23 
     24 

ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.12.0
your numpy version is 1.11.0.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.12.0 to use this pandas version
```

in the same notebook, when I give the command,

```
!pip install pandas,
```

the output is

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas) (2014.10)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.10.0)
cheetah 2.4.4 requires Markdown>=2.0.1, which is not installed.
You are using pip version 10.0.0, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am not familiar with software environment, so kindly help me how to correct this.( The problem is Pandas require a numpy package >1.12.0 but the numpy package in .../dist-packages is 1.16.2. this is my understanding)

Comment: `import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)` What do you get?

Comment: can you update your `pip` then try installing your required libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in such situations

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: How do I run this? I get a sytax error on the `!` when running it in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install markdown
pip install --upgrade numpy
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install using the following command:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas
```

rather than just `!pip install pandas` - this will ensure that you are using the right pip for associated with the kernel.